# Rails - Dynamically generate PDF from HTML and show link to download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, pdfkit

I have a rails application in which a user can click a link on a page and a little popup opens up with some HTML on it. I'd like to put another link next to it called 'Download as PDF' and when someone clicks this link, I'd like to dynamically generate a PDF from the HTML and allow the user to download the generated PDF onto their system. I've seen a few pages on stackoverflow which talk about using pdfkit to generate pdf from html but nothing about dynamically generating the pdf and then making it available to download. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using gem prawn 
Here is youtube of how to upload it to your ruby on rails website https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW5zwqj37Lo&t=233s
https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

Here is example of how to add gem prawn
    gem 'prawn', '~> 1.2.1'
    gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0’

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf

def index
    @users = User.order("id DESC").all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text “hello
        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'member.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
<%= link_to 'PDF File', members_path(format: 'pdf') %>

def index
        @users = User.order("id DESC").all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf do
            pdf = MemberPdf.new(@users)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: 'member.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: "inline"
          end
        end
      end
```

pdfs folder
member_pdf.rb

```
class MemberPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(users)
    super(top_margin: 170)
    @users=User.order("id DESC").all
    user_id
  end

  def user_id
    move_down 20
    table user_id_row do
      row(0).font_style = :bold
      columns(1..3).align = :right
      self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD","FFFFFF"]
      self.header = true
    end
  end

def user_id_row
    [["id","First","Middle","LastName","Email","Address","Address2","City","PostalCode","phone","Status","Child","Intrest"]] +
    @users.map do |user| 
      [user.id,user.first_name,user.middle_name,user.last_name,user.email,user.street_address,user.street_address2,user.city,user.postal_code,user.phone_number,user.status,user.child,user.interest]    
    end
  end
end
```